# hibernate create schema form another

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

Is it possible to create an schema in hibernate from another? I mean, to create a method and only pass the name of the schema like parameter and hibernate create it automatically.. ?

Sorry for my bad english.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Looked at the docs?

Comment: Yes, i did it but i couldnt found anything :/